# Httpd processes bring CPU down (99% usage)

Tags: apache

I run a Mac OS X Server Yosemite with 6 virtual hosts. 
Pretty normal Wordpress stuff, nothing very special.

For 2 days now, when I start the server, the CPU usage goes up to 750% immediately (I have an Intel Quad-Core) and the pages are very slow, sometime I even get a "MySQL too many connections" error.

My machine is a Mac mini quad core 2.3 Ghz with 16 GB of Ram.

I had the server running for 3 months without any similar problems.

Do you think it's an DDOS attack?

Thx,
Matthias

Comment: We cannot tell you about an attack. You have to consult your http servers log files to answer that question.

Comment: But more likely than a DOS or a DDOS attack is that your wordpress site has been hacked and acts as a zombie now. Happens all the time with wordpress. So you want to check your scripts and outgoing network traffic.

Comment: How can I see if it's been hijacked? The Irritating thing is, the usage goes up immediately, from 0 to 100 as soon as the server starts...

Comment: Well, some of the scripts usually get changed. So compare a checksum to a fresh install or something. Also the file permissions can give away a manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. It was a ddos attack at my wordpress site. A bot was trying to brute-force the xmlrpc.php file in the root folder of my wordpress installation, guessing usernames and passwords via mysql. 
I simply added

```
// in xmlrpc.php
<?php exit; ?>
```

at the beginning of xmlrpc.php, and now there is peace on earth again.